# Kubernetes + MySQL : Creating custom database and user in a Kubernetes container

Tags: mysql, django, docker, kubernetes

I am trying to create a Django + MySQL app using Google Container Engine and Kubernetes. Following the docs from official MySQL docker image and Kubernetes docs for creating MySQL container I have created the following replication controller

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  labels:
    name: mysql
  name: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.6.33
        name: mysql
        env:
          #Root password is compulsory
        - name: "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
          value: "root_password"
        - name: "MYSQL_DATABASE"
          value: "custom_db"
        - name: "MYSQL_USER"
          value: "custom_user"
        - name: "MYSQL_PASSWORD"
          value: "custom_password"
        ports:
        - name: mysql
          containerPort: 3306
        volumeMounts:
          # This name must match the volumes.name below.
          - name: mysql-persistent-storage
            mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          gcePersistentDisk:
            # This disk must already exist.
            pdName: mysql-disk
            fsType: ext4
```

According to the docs, passing the environment variables MYSQL_DATABASE. MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD, a new user will be created with that password and assigned rights to the newly created database. But this does not happen. When I SSH into that container, the ROOT password is set. But neither the user, nor the database is created.

I have tested this by running locally and passing the same environment variables like this

```
docker run -d --name some-mysql \
    -e MYSQL_USER="custom_user" \
    -e MYSQL_DATABASE="custom_db" \
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="root_password" \
    -e MYSQL_PASSWORD="custom_password" \
    mysql
```

When I SSH into that container, the database and users are created and everything works fine.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Could anyone please point out my mistake. I have been at this the whole day.

EDIT: 20-sept-2016

As Requested
@Julien Du Bois 
The disk is created. it appears in the cloud console and when I run the describe command I get the following output

```
Command : gcloud compute disks describe mysql-disk

Result: 
creationTimestamp: '2016-09-16T01:06:23.380-07:00'
id: '4673615691045542160'
kind: compute#disk
lastAttachTimestamp: '2016-09-19T06:11:23.297-07:00'
lastDetachTimestamp: '2016-09-19T05:48:14.320-07:00'
name: mysql-disk
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<details-withheld-by-me>/disks/mysql-disk
sizeGb: '20'
status: READY
type: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<details-withheld-by-me>/diskTypes/pd-standard
users:
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<details-withheld-by-me>/instances/gke-cluster-1-default-pool-e0f09576-zvh5
zone: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<details-withheld-by-me>
```

I referred to lot of tutorials and google cloud examples. To run the mysql docker container locally my main reference was the official image page on docker hub
https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

This works for me and locally the container created has a new database and user with right privileges.

For kubernetes, my main reference was the following

https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/persistent-disk/

I am just trying to connect to it using Django container.

Comment: Is you disk created on GCE ? Can you show the log output please.

Comment: Can you link to the docs you're referring to?

Comment: @JulienDuBois and Anirudh Ramanathan. I have edited the question with further details as requested. please let me know if anything else is needed. Currently I have SSHed into the container and have created the required user and db to continue the development. I still need a way to automate this process once I want to deploy for production.

Comment: were you able to get this running? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue when I was using volumes and mounting them to mysql pods.

As mentioned in the documentation of [mysql's docker image](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/mysql/):

> When you start the mysql image, you can adjust the configuration of the MySQL instance by passing one or more environment variables on the docker run command line. **Do note that none of the variables below will have any effect if you start the container with a data directory that already contains a database: any pre-existing database will always be left untouched on container startup.**

So after spinning wheels I managed to solve the problem by changing the hostPath of the volume that I was creating from "/data/mysql-pv-volume" to "/var/lib/mysql"

Here is a code snippet that might help create the volumes

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete /* For development Purposes only */
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/var/lib/mysql"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

You set mysql-disk in your deployment and the disk you have is custom-disk. Change pdName to custom-disk and it will work.

Comment: I am really sorry. Its my mistake. I am editing the names as I am not sure how much information I must protect when posting on a public platform. I will change that. But the disk name is correct. As I mentioned in the question, I went into that container, created the DB and then connected Django with it and it works fine. But the db is not being created when I create the pod.